# Access to heroku logs without access to app itself

Tags: heroku

Say, i have a team of developers. I want them to have access to production logs, but nothing else. Preferably they shouldn't even know the heroku's internal app name.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible (at the moment) with Heroku command line. You have two options:

1. Use one of the [logging addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons) and give your teammates access to the logging app only
2. Write yourself a log drain for [Heroku logplex](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logplex) route the logs to AWS S3, your own DB or other, then give your teammates some way to view the logs.